# bootstrap modal dialog box not appearing in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

I have a modal dialog box that is supposed to show up, the code is as follows:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="#" class="btn-link" class="btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><asp:Button ID="btnSimpan" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="SIMPAN"  /></a>
               </div> 
      </div>              
 </div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal Content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:red;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Makluman</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Adakah Anda Pasti ?</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Ya" /></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <span class="pull-left">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Tidak" /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code simple does nothing, nothing happens when i click btnSimpan button,
like this:

[The output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ1ll.png)

looked at many examples on the internet and they all appear the same.I'm guessing I must be missing a something somewhere, unless the error is with my code, any one any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Why you need `in` class for modal? This class will be added when the modal is shown. If the backdrop is only displaying and modal doesn't, please check whether you missed to close any `div` tags.

Also, why you need to use an Asp.Net server side controll, such as `asp:Button` to call modal open function? Since you used the button control inside anchor tag which may resulting in a postback event that will reload the page.

You can either use a simple anchor tag with `data-target` attribute as below:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn-link" class="btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success"></a>
```

If you want to trigger the modal open function on asp:button click function, then use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` as below on button click event.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSimpan" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="btnSimpan_Click" Text="SIMPAN"  />
```

c#

```
protected void btnSimpan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "", "<script>$(function () {$('#myModal').modal('show');});</script>", false);
}
```